# BigQuery select * except nested column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What I want to do should be simple: Given a BigQuery schema, I want to select all tables (including nested ones) apart from a few. The tricky thing is that BigQuery has a nested structure and the few I want to exclude are nested within other records.

I've found the SELECT * except clause in the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-modifiers) which seems very promising. The problem is that it doesn't seem to support the nested structure exclusion.

For example, using the public github_nested dataset we can write a query like

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * except (payload) FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested` LIMIT 1000
```

This does what we expect successfully by removing the payload record from the results. Let's imagine now that we only want to remove payload.comment, thereby preserving the rest of the payload record contents in the response. I tried

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * except (payload.comment) FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested` LIMIT 1000
```

However, this fails.

Anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The way to think of the problem is that you still want a `payload` column in the result, but you want it to have a different structure, namely to exclude `comment`. In this case, you can use `SELECT * REPLACE` to make the modification. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE ((SELECT AS STRUCT payload.* EXCEPT (comment)) AS payload)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested`
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Thank you, Elliott. This does indeed solve the issue I outlined above. Unfortunately I have been a terrible question poster and realized that my case was a little trickier with a repeated field (which is not in the example). I'll add an update to the question. Again, apologies!

Comment: If this answers the original question, do you mind marking it as accepted? Feel free to post another variant of the question that relates to repeated fields. Thanks!

Comment: If that's the convention used on stackoverflow, sure. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -2):

This too works:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  * 
  EXCEPT (payload),
  payload.desc AS payload_desc,  
  payload.action AS payload_action
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested`
```