# BigQuery except double nested column

Tags: select, google-bigquery

Hi need to exclude the column `hits.latencyTracking.userTimingLabel` from my table and select all the other columns. How can I do this in Standard Sql?
I found already a question on a similar problem ([BigQuery select * except nested column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019739/bigquery-select-except-nested-column)) but in my case I have a double nested column and I am not able do adapt the code.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are my few cents on this:
I think it answers your exact question / case

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT hit.* 
      REPLACE((SELECT AS STRUCT latencyTracking.* EXCEPT(userTimingLabel)) AS latencyTracking)
    FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hit
  ) AS hits)
FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.yourTable`
```

I tested it on public table as below:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT hit.* 
      REPLACE((SELECT AS STRUCT page.* EXCEPT(hostname)) AS page)
    FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hit
  ) AS hits)
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`
```

Answer (score 1):

If `hits` is an array and `latencyTracking` is a struct, then:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT (SELECT AS STRUCT latencyTracking.* EXCEPT(userTimingLabel)) AS latencyTracking FROM UNNEST(hits)) AS hits
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between [select * except nested column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019739/bigquery-select-except-nested-column) and your question, is due to the fact that `hits` is an ARRAY. Here is how you can exclude columns from array of structs:

```
SELECT * REPLACE 
 (ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(page) FROM UNNEST(hits) h) AS hits)
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`
```