# BigQuery - Select multiple columns and want to exclude two double nested columns

Tags: select, google-bigquery

Hi I am working on the `lt-pcf-analytics-exp.90676036.ga_sessions_*` table and I need to extract different variables along including all variables from the nested hits columns except the columns `hits.customDimensions.value` and `hits.customDimensions.index`. I think both hits and `hits.customDimensions` are **ARRAY**. How can I do this in Standard SQL?

I found already a question on a similar problem ([BigQuery except double nested column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091066/bigquery-except-double-nested-column)), but in my case I have a double nested array column and I am not able do adapt the code.

Basically, this is what I want to extract. How can I modify it so I will exclude `hits.customDimensions.value` and `hits.customDimensions.index`? Thank you.

```sql
SELECT fullVisitorId,
   visitId,
   visitNumber,
   cd.value as PCF_CUST_ID,
   date,
   TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) as visitStartTime,
   totals.visits as visits,
   totals.hits as total_hits,
   hits.* (EXCEPT hits.customDimensions.value and hits.customDimensions.index)
FROM `lt-pcf-analytics-exp.90676036.ga_sessions_*` as t
          left join unnest(customDimensions) as cd
          left join unnest(hits) as hits
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '20210101' and '20210131' 
   and cd.index = 4 and cd.value is not null
ORDER BY PCF_CUST_ID, visitStartTime, hitNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @martinus noticed, your except syntax is not correct. If you take a look to the [BigQuery Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_list), you will see that the correct way to run a Query with an except is:

```sql
SELECT 
   field.* EXCEPT (nested_field1, nested_field2)
FROM `my_table`
```

Nevertheless, you can not directly use `EXCEPT` on a nested field directly. As a workaround you can exclude all the `hits.customDimensions` values from `hits.*`, and then `SELECT` for only `hits.customDimensions.*` and then exclude the nested elements that you need to remove, like `index` and `value`.

A query like the following should work:

```sql
SELECT fullVisitorId,
   visitId,
   visitNumber,
   cd.value as PCF_CUST_ID,
   date,
   TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) as visitStartTime,
   totals.visits as visits,
   totals.hits as total_hits,
   hits.* EXCEPT (hits.customDimensions),
   hits.customDimensions.* EXCEPT (index, value)
FROM `lt-pcf-analytics-exp.90676036.ga_sessions_*` as t
          left join unnest(customDimensions) as cd
          left join unnest(hits) as hits
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '20210101' and '20210131' 
   and cd.index = 4 and cd.value is not null
ORDER BY PCF_CUST_ID, visitStartTime, hitNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [BigQuery documentation for except](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_list), this is not the good syntax:

```
SELECT [ AS { typename | STRUCT | VALUE } ] [{ ALL | DISTINCT }]
    { [ expression. ]* [ EXCEPT ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
        [ REPLACE ( expression [ AS ] column_name [, ...] ) ]
    | expression [ [ AS ] alias ] } [, ...]
```

So, use it like this:

```sql
SELECT hits.* EXCEPT (value, index)
```