# Big query remove column nested in STRUCT object

Tags: google-bigquery

I am encountering some troubles to delete one column from my bigquery table.
I have a STRUCT object called `jsonPayload`.
This fields has may sub-fields.
e.g:

```
jsonPayload.source
jsonPayload.status
jsonPayload.markers.message_timestamp
jsonPayload.markers.id
```

and I want to remove the column `jsonPayload.markers.message_timestamp` which is a string without removing any others fields.

It is quite the same situation of this thread [BigQuery select expect double nested column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925593/bigquery-select-expect-double-nested-column) but when I execute this, it removes all the jsonPayload.* like `jsonPayload.source`

I can't find the right syntax to do this. Someone can help me ?

**Edit:**

Here is the data structure of my bigquery table:

| Field name | Type | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `jsonPayload` | RECORD | NULLABLE |
| `jsonPayload.source` | STRING | NULLABLE |
| `jsonPayload.msg` | STRING | NULLABLE |
| `jsonPayload.level` | STRING | NULLABLE |
| `jsonPayload.err` | STRING | NULLABLE |
| `jsonPayload.timestamp` | STRING | NULLABLE |
| `jsonPayload.markers.message_partition` | FLOAT | NULLABLE |
| `jsonPayload.markers.message_topic` | STRING | NULLABLE |
| `jsonPayload.markers.message_offset` | FLOAT | NULLABLE |
| `jsonPayload.markers.message_timestamp` | STRING | NULLABLE |

Just want to remove the last column(`jsonPayload.markers.message_timestamp`) and keep all the others.

I've tried this one but it seems to delete also all fields that are not markers (`jsonPayload.source`,...):

```
SELECT * REPLACE(
  (SELECT AS STRUCT(SELECT AS STRUCT jsonPayload.markers.* EXCEPT (message_timestamp)))
  AS jsonPayload)
FROM mytable.dataset
```

Thanks

Comment: not clear - is it STRUCT or JSON - provide example of data and expected output so we can help

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I've added an extract of the data structure to better explain the issue I'm facing of.

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select * replace(
  (select as struct jsonPayload.* replace(
    (select as struct jsonPayload.markers.* except(message_timestamp))
    as markers
  )
  ) AS jsonPayload) 
from `project.dataset.table`
```